# How to create a regional google heatmap

Tags: heat, regional

For a real estate project I need to demonstrate the property rates by regional(not markers) on google map by means of geochart/intensitymap/ drilldown highchart. I found that geochart is not capable to show states. The map I need is of Australian suburbs not the five states.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid at this point in time the answer is: Google's GeoChart for Oz doesn't offer suburb level imagery.

Early last year I went to a networking function in Brisvegas where someone was pitching http://viewdata.io/ which looked interesting, but I didn't investigate very thoroughly because Google's state&territory map was good enough for my project.

Furthermore, there is a pile of urls being thrown around over at this aussie whirlpool thread: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2184431 "Creating a Heatmap using Postcodes".

Good luck.